# The image "path" cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php, drupal, mpdf

The following error is generated by drupal site creating an image using `imagecreatefromjpeg` and `imagejpeg`:

> The image “http://domain.com/dbtransfer” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

I enabled error display and checked the error log but no errors are display. There aren't any messages displaying. All the paths are correct as well as all variables are correct.

Creating and writing data into mpdf image but it's not working here.

```
$img=imagecreatefromjpeg(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/themes/journalcrunch/images/pdfbg.jpg');       
$image_text="Publisher:";
$image_text1="$publisherpdf";
$image_text2="Pricing:";
$image_text3="Single User License:";
$image_text4="US $ $sulpdf";
$image_text5="Corporate User License:";
$image_text6="US $ $culpdf";
$image_text7="Category:";
$image_text8="$categoriespdf";
$image_text9="No. of Pages: $pagespdf";
$red=rand(100,30); 
$green=rand(100,60);
$blue=rand(100,95);
$text_color=imagecolorallocate($img,30,60,95);
$text=imagettftext($img,9,0,25,145,$text_color,"fonts/arialbd.ttf",$image_text);
$text=imagettftext($img,10,0,25,170,$text_color,"fonts/arialbd.ttf",$image_text1);
$text=imagettftext($img,10,0,25,215,$text_color,"fonts/arialbd.ttf",$image_text2);
$text=imagettftext($img,9,0,25,235,$text_color,"fonts/arialbd.ttf",$image_text3);
$text=imagettftext($img,9,0,25,255,$text_color,"fonts/arialbd.ttf",$image_text4);
$text=imagettftext($img,9,0,25,275,$text_color,"fonts/arialbd.ttf",$image_text5);
$text=imagettftext($img,9,0,25,295,$text_color,"fonts/arialbd.ttf",$image_text6);
$text=imagettftext($img,9,0,25,340,$text_color,"fonts/arialbd.ttf",$image_text7);
$text=imagettftext($img,10,0,25,365,$text_color,"fonts/arialbd.ttf",$image_text8);
$text=imagettftext($img,10,0,25,410,$text_color,"fonts/arialbd.ttf",$image_text9);

header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
header("Content-Disposition:inline ; filename=secure.jpg"); 
imagejpeg($img,"images/".$lastnid.".jpg",100);
```

Comment: go to admin/reports/dblog and see if there is more information regarding that.  What do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited image file and found error in it. Its fixed now.